# SQLAlchemy, querying nested jsonb values returns empty list every time

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy

Given the following model:

```py
from . import db 
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB


class Info(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), nullable=False, unique=True)
    meta = db.Column(JSONB, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Config {}>'.format(self.name)
```

and the following data:

```json
{
  "name": "pudding"
  "meta": {
    "available_in": {
      "cups": true
     }
  }
}
```

I'm wanting to Query the `cups` field in side of the meta field. I've looked at various examples and it hasn't worked for me, my list keeps returning a blank list.

```py
query = db.session.query(Info).filter(Info.meta['available_in', 'cups'].astext=='true').all()

# returns []
```

Anyone know the right way to do this?

Comment: filter has 2 parameters. 1 is function other is data. you only passed1

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy makes nested JSONB elements into a nested Python dictionary, so you should access them using `Info.meta['available_in']['cups']` instead. Secondly, cast `Info.meta['available_in', 'cups'].astext` to a boolean first, then compare it to `sqlalchemy.True()` or just as is.

```
query = db.session.query(Info)\
    .filter(Info.meta['available_in']['cups'].as_boolean()).all()
```

The SQL query it returns is

```sql
SELECT info.id,
       info.name,
       info.meta
FROM info
WHERE CAST((info.meta -> 'available_in') ->> 'cups' AS BOOLEAN)
```

Thanks to @snakecharmerb for pointing out that [`comparator.as_boolean`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON.Comparator.as_boolean) now exists.

Comment: You're welcome.  I couldn't get the [key1][key2] selection to work, hence my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the docs for the JSON type, you need to provide the key path as a tuple.

The result can be cast to a boolean using the [comparator.as_boolean](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html#sqlalchemy.types.JSON.Comparator.as_boolean) data caster if you are using SQLAlchemy 1.3.11 or later, otherwise you need to cast as described in the docs.

```
session.query(Info).filter(Info.meta[('available_in', 'cups')].as_boolean())
```